# can I run a command in Tkinter without Button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

so basically I'm trying to make a command line interface using python and I have text area where commands are being entered.
what I wanted to achieve is each command is executing without pressing the button at all( simply on pressing enter)

Comment: You are looking for `bind()`. Something like `text_field.bind('<Return>', function_name)`. From inside the function you can read and execute what is in the text box.

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: If you work through most any basic tkinter tutorial it will teach you about binding functions to events (for example, pressing the return key can be considered an event).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Enter key to a function with `.bind('<Return>', function)`.